# Filtering RSS feed content by category using an API call

Tags: xml, rss, blogspot

I am working on an application that is required to 'categorize' an RSS feed from a blog on [blogspot.com](http://www.blogger.com). Now as we all know, RSS feeds are recorded in XMLs as 'items', which have many different attributes. One of them is an attribute called 'category'. My problem is that I want the feeds including only items pertaining to the category (as in item.category attribute), say 'xyz'. The default feed URL on blogspot is :

*http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss*

Is there any alternate URL (API call) that will allow me to filter this feed according to the category 'xyz' ? Something similar to :

*http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?item.category=xyz&alt=rss*

The API mentioned above is certainly incorrect. It is written only to highlight that I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer on [Google Help Center](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries):

There are "label" specific feeds which have the category name in its url.

Eg posts/articles with label "privacy" will be in this feed:

Atom 1.0: http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/privacy

RSS 2.0: http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/privacy?alt=rss

Answer (score 0):

Just for some additional info, RSS and Atom channels are made as simple as possible. It's best for the server to always just build the channel when some article is or modified.

The API calls you mentioned look rather like you wanted it to make some search and return results. News syndication doesn't work this way. But as you replied to yourself, there can be multiple RSS channels for one web page, giving you several pre-filtered options.

That is a great idea if only a small subset of categories are your interest. However, it seems you want to categorize one whole blog on blogspot (or even more of them). In this case, I would suggest reading the feed that contains all the items and categorize them yourself. This way you don't need to know all the categories yourself. If you happen to find a category you haven't seen yet, you just create a new one.